# Android app does not show up in App store > 24 hours

Tags: android

I released my first android app yesterday, and got the direct link to the app working after 6 hours. But Its been > 24 hours now, and it still doesnt show up in the search on playstore.

I have been searching in the playstore both from my android device, as well as from desktop browser. The app simply isnt there.

Is this common? Is there something I can do to check the status/find out whats happening?

Thanks a lot

EDIT: the direct link is: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.droidinput

EDIT: The issue was indeed that the name "Droid Input" was too general. Changed it to Moused . Hopefully it makes it a tad better once the update is pushed to prod. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I can't find it by searching by name, I think something is unusual here. Maybe you can try changing the title, try something with more keywords in the title.

Comment: The app is pretty cool actually!

Comment: @svenoaks Thanks! I think thats the problem, going to edit the title a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes newly published apps take time until they appear in search results. The app needs to be indexed in the Play Store before it starts appearing in search results. Also, make sure the app name has enough unique keywords so that it's easier to spot while searching.

Comment: Issue related to this...If I search with my App name and Developer name together, it shows up. It gets buried underneath hundreds of results even though none of them are exact name matches...:(

Comment: Don't go just by the "name" given to the app. The result shown in Play Store for the term "Droid Input" is because the package name (URL) contains those keywords. Plus, those apps outrank your app in terms of downloads, reviews, life time, and so on. The visibility rank for your app is low. The better you market your app (get more downloads, reviews, etc.) the faster it bubbles up the list.

Comment: Yes I got it now :) Changed the app name to make it more relevant and will also market it and hopefully see it improving soon. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All my apps were searchable minutes after the direct link started working. Can you post the name of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Check those in Developer console

1. published area
2. minimal Android os
3. make sure it's published in developer console

If it's all right, don't worry, just wait to published
If your app have any problem google will send email to you

Answer (score 0):

First of all,
you must check if you have no other updates,
second check if the website is not under going several changes if so than you might have to wait a couple of days
check your device for any out of the normal activity 
if this is not resolved make sure to contact the company and explain them your issue,
regularly it shouldn't be happening to only you so there might be others with the same issue as you, it is unlikely that it could be your device but there is always that possibility that it might.